# JAVA maven JSP won't load css file

Tags: java, css, jsp

I'm creating the simple web app using the jsp-servlet. 
I have created the maven project via InteliJ IDE.
The issue is that the .css file seems not to load correctly.
I tired different solutions like changing the form of link, changing the project structure but nothing work for me... Could you please give me some advise?

project structure

[image]

the css file is simply changing the background-color
Thank you in advance!
Lukasz.

Comment: can you add your dispatcher-servlet

Answer (score 1):

Add this to web mvc dispatcher servlet xml configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

and change the link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I put folowing maping to the web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and I have change the link to and change the link to:

```
 <link href="resources/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

now it works fine :)